# Api Java ElasticSearch | Search by passing a list and returning all matchs

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to do a search on elastic search, but I'm having difficulties

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = boolQuery()
            .must(matchQuery(CLIENT_ID, clientId));

fieldValues
      .forEach(fieldValue -> query.must(boolQuery().should(matchQuery(FIELD_NAME, fieldValue))));
```

First I want all the data to match the client. It's ok

*fieldValues* is a string list. I would like to have the result of a match of all the values that I have in the list woth the FIELD_NAME field. But the way I implemented it, it always results 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the query would look like using Elasticsearch Query DSL

> ```
> {
>   "query": {
>     "bool": {
>       "should": [
>         {
>           "bool": {
>             "must": [
>               {
>                 "match": {
>                   "clientId": CLIENT_ID
>                 }
>               }
>             ],
>             "should": [
>               {
>                 "terms": {
>                   "FIELD_NAME": [
>                     YOUR_TERMS
>                   ]
>                 }
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Transforming it into Java API will look like:

```
BoolQueryBuilder mainBoolQuery = boolQuery();
BoolQueryBuilder innerBoolQuery = boolQuery();
MatchQueryBuilder clientMatchQueryBuilder = matchQuery(CLIENT_ID, clientId);
innerBoolQuery.must(clientMatchQueryBuilder);
fieldValues.forEach(value -> {
    TermQueryBuilder fieldNamesTermQueryBuilder = termQuery(FIELD_NAME, value);
    innerBoolQuery.must(fieldNamesTermQueryBuilder);

});
mainBoolQuery.should(innerBoolQuery);
```

Comment: Hey man. It still doesn't work, because it returns everything that matched the client field. And what I would like is that everything that matches the client first, then everything that came with it, matches the rest. sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: Yes .. I didn't know this guy: TermsQueryBuilder. With him and taking the client and putting on a must, I did it. Thank you man